# cbind with do.call stores dataframe name in column variable

Tags: r

Why do I have different column names here for test1 and test2? If I change the data frame to only one column, they have the same name. I would like to have them the same name but use the do.call function.

```
a <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,2,3), col2 = c(1,2,3))
b <- data.frame(col3 = c(1,2,3), col4 = c(1,2,3))

test1 = cbind(a, b)


dataframe_name = c("a", "b")
test2 <- do.call(cbind, mget(dataframe_name, envir = .GlobalEnv))

colnames(test1)
colnames(test2)


# only one column
a=a[1]
b=b[1]
test1 = cbind(a, b)
test2 <- do.call(cbind, mget(dataframe_name, envir = .GlobalEnv))
colnames(test1)
colnames(test2)
```

Comment: `test2 <- do.call(cbind, unname(mget(dataframe_name, envir = .GlobalEnv)))`